# C++ How do I make sure file is not overwritten between program runs when adding new contacts to a contact list?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to create a program for a simple contact book which takes information about a contact from the user and saves it in a file. When I re-run the program and open the same file next time, I obviously want all the contacts I added previously to still be there and not be overwritten if I choose to add new contacts (or just exit the program without adding any new contacts for that matter).
But I can't get the file to save properly. I can get contacts added to a map, but depending on where I put the saveToFile() the file always overwrites contacts at some point, either after adding a new contact or between program runs.

Here is my class for the contact book and function calls in main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

struct Contact {
   std::string name;
   std::string address;
   std::string email;
   std::string number;
   std::string bday;
   std::string other;
}

class ContactBook { 
   private:
   std::map<std::string, Contact> contacts; 

   public:
   void ContactBook::loadFromFile(const std::string filename) {
        std::ifstream file(filename);
        if (!file) {
            std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl;
            return;
        }  
        
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(file, line)) {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            Contact contact;
            if (std::getline(iss, contact.name, '\n') &&
                std::getline(iss, contact.address, '\n') &&
                std::getline(iss, contact.email, '\n') &&
                std::getline(iss, contact.number, '\n') &&
                std::getline(iss, contact.bday, '\n') &&
                std::getline(iss, contact.other, '\n')) {
                    contacts[contact.name] = contact;
                }
        }
        file.close();
        std::cout << "File " << filename << " loaded" << std::endl;
    }
    
  void ContactBook::addContact(const Contact& contact) {
    contacts[contact.name] = contact;   
  } 

  void ContactBook::saveToFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(filename);
    for (const auto& pair : contacts) {
        const Contact& contact = pair.second;
        file << contact.name <<  '\n' <<
            contact.address << '\n' <<
            contact.email << '\n' <<
            contact.number << '\n' <<
            contact.bday << '\n' <<
            contact.other << '\n';
            
    } file.close();
  }

 void ContactBook::printFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(filename);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        while(std::getline(file, line)) {
            std::cout << line << '\n';
        }
        file.close();
    }
  }
}


int main() {

    ContactBook contactBook;
    contactBook.load("contacts.txt");
    int alt;
    bool exit = false;
    
    while (!exit) {
    std::cout << "1 - Add contact" << '\n' <<
             "2 - Remove contact" << '\n' <<   //will add later
             "3 - Search for contact" << '\n' << //will add later
             "4 - Save and exit" << '\n' <<
             "5 - Print contact list" << std::endl;
    
    std::cin >> alt;
    
    switch(alt) {
        case 1: {Contact contact;
            std::cin.ignore();  
            std::cout << "Name: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, contact.name);
            std::cout << "Address: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, contact.address);
            std::cout << "Email: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, contact.email);
            std::cout << "Phone number: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, contact.number);
            std::cout << "Birthday: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, contact.bday);
            std::cout << "Other info: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, contact.other);
            
            contactBook.addContact(contact);
            }
            break;
        case 2: /*...*/
            break;
        case 3: /*..*/
            break;
        case 4: contactBook.saveToFile("contacts.txt");
            exit = true;
            break;
        case 5: contactBook.printFile("contacts.txt");
            break;
        default: std::cout << "invalid input" << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As of now, if I add a contact, save, and re-run the program and choose print, the previously added contact will be printed correctly. However, if I save and exit a second time, then the next run the file will be empty.
The first contact will also be gone if a add another contact during the same program run - if I save and exit the file will contain only the second contact.

Sorry if I'm making a super dumb and obvious mistake here - I'm a beginner. But I just can't figure it out and I've been stuck with this for hours to the point where I can't really focus on what I'm doing anymore, help much appreciated.

Comment: This has exactly nothing to do with [tag:oop] or [tag:user-interaction]. It is about [tag:iostream]. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: One way to do this robustly is to use SQLite to manage the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are reading the file can never work, because by default `std::getline()` stops reading when it encounters `'\n'`, so it can never output a `std::string` that has a `'\n'` in it. But you are expecting multiple fields to be on a single line delimited by `'\n'`, which is nonsense.

The 1st iteration of the `while` loop will read in only the 1st contact's `name` into the `istringstream`, then the subsequent `if` will fail to read in the remaining values since they don't exist in the `istringstream`. Then the next `while` iteration will read in the 1st contact's `address` into the `istringstream`, and the `if` will subsequently fail. And so on.

To do what you are attempting, use a different delimiter instead, such as `'\t'`, eg:

```
void ContactBook::loadFromFile(const std::string filename) {
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }  
        
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        Contact contact;
        if (std::getline(iss, contact.name, '\t') &&
            std::getline(iss, contact.address, '\t') &&
            std::getline(iss, contact.email, '\t') &&
            std::getline(iss, contact.number, '\t') &&
            std::getline(iss, contact.bday, '\t') &&
            std::getline(iss, contact.other))
        {
            contacts[contact.name] = contact;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    std::cout << "File " << filename << " loaded" << std::endl;
}
    
void ContactBook::saveToFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ofstream file(filename);
    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "Unable to create file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }  

    for (const auto& pair : contacts) {
        const Contact& contact = pair.second;
        file << contact.name <<  '\t' <<
                contact.address << '\t' <<
                contact.email << '\t' <<
                contact.number << '\t' <<
                contact.bday << '\t' <<
                contact.other << '\n';            
    }
    file.close();
    std::cout << "File " << filename << " saved" << std::endl;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to use `'\n'` to delimit your fields, then you need to get rid of the `std::istringstream` and just read the lines from the `std::ifstream` directly, eg:

```
void ContactBook::loadFromFile(const std::string filename) {
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }  
        
    Contact contact;
    while (std::getline(file, contact.name) &&
           std::getline(file, contact.address) &&
           std::getline(file, contact.email) &&
           std::getline(file, contact.number) &&
           std::getline(file, contact.bday) &&
           std::getline(file, contact.other))
    {
        contacts[contact.name] = contact;
    }
    file.close();
    std::cout << "File " << filename << " loaded" << std::endl;
}
    
void ContactBook::saveToFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ofstream file(filename);
    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "Unable to create file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }  

    for (const auto& pair : contacts) {
        const Contact& contact = pair.second;
        file << contact.name <<  '\n' <<
                contact.address << '\n' <<
                contact.email << '\n' <<
                contact.number << '\n' <<
                contact.bday << '\n' <<
                contact.other << '\n';
    }
    file.close();
    std::cout << "File " << filename << " saved" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Of course! can't believe I missed that. Thank you, you're a life saver!